# ERC20 token not showing up in search

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I just created a new ERC20 token on the ropsten testnet. The contract is verified and can be seend here. However when I try to search for AtariToken or ATAR I don't get any results on ropsten.etherscan.io. Is there something I'm missing. Heres the contract code:

```
    /**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2020-05-14
*/

pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract AtariToken {

string public constant name = "AtariToken";
string public constant symbol = "ATAR";
uint8 public constant decimals = 0;

event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
event RegistrationSuccessful(uint256 nonce);
event RegistrationFailed(uint256 nonce);

mapping(address => uint256) balances;

mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

uint256 totalSupply_ = 7771107723;

mapping (string => address) addressTable;

using SafeMath for uint256;

constructor( uint256 _totalSupply) public{
    totalSupply_ = _totalSupply;
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
}

function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
}

function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint) {
    return balances[tokenOwner];
}

function balanceOf(string memory tokenOwner) public view returns (uint) {
    address userAddress;
    userAddress = addressTable[tokenOwner];
    return balances[userAddress];
}

function transfer(address receiver, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
    require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function transfer(string memory receiver, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
    address receiverAddress;
    receiverAddress = addressTable[receiver];
    require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[receiverAddress] = balances[receiverAddress].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiverAddress, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function approve(address delegate, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function approve(string memory delegate, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
    address delegateAddress;
    delegateAddress = addressTable[delegate];
    allowed[msg.sender][delegateAddress] = numTokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, delegateAddress, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public view returns (uint) {
    return allowed[owner][delegate];
}

function allowance(string memory owner, string memory delegate) public view returns (uint) {
    address ownerAddress;
    ownerAddress = addressTable[owner];
    address delegateAddress;
    delegateAddress = addressTable[delegate];
    return allowed[ownerAddress][delegateAddress];
}

 function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
    require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);    
    require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

    balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
    allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(string memory owner, string memory buyer, uint numTokens) public returns (bool) {
    address ownerAddress;
    ownerAddress = addressTable[owner];
    address buyerAddress;
    buyerAddress = addressTable[buyer];

    require(numTokens <= balances[ownerAddress]);    
    require(numTokens <= allowed[ownerAddress][msg.sender]);

    balances[ownerAddress] = balances[ownerAddress].sub(numTokens);
    allowed[ownerAddress][msg.sender] = allowed[ownerAddress][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[buyerAddress] = balances[buyerAddress].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(ownerAddress, buyerAddress, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function registerUser(string memory user, uint256 nonce) public returns (bool) {
    if (addressTable[user] == address(0)) {
        addressTable[user] = msg.sender;
        emit RegistrationSuccessful(nonce);
        return true;
    } else {
        emit RegistrationFailed(nonce);
        return false;
    }
}
}

library SafeMath { 
function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  assert(b <= a);
  return a - b;
}

function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  uint256 c = a + b;
  assert(c >= a);
  return c;
}
```

}

Comment: Out of interest are you working on the AtariToken?  In a previous life I worked on the Atari Platform Network.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search and assume this is your token:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xEFdb43c081eeE890A03AD7E78bbA98397A6B8528

If you are creating ERC20 tokens you may want to look at the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation to see if this meets your needs. See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*